# mousedown Events in RaphaelJS not working

Tags: javascript, events, raphael, mouse

I have run into the problem that RaphaelJS doesn't react to mousedown/mousemove/mouseup Events but works fine with .click().

I created this http://jsfiddle.net/JMu7Z/2/ to show what i mean.

**JS code:**

```
var containerDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
var overlayDiv = null;
for(var k=0;k<containerDivs[0].childNodes.length;k++)
{
    if (containerDivs[0].childNodes[k].className.indexOf("holder") !== -1)
        overlayDiv = containerDivs[0].childNodes[k];
}
var canvas  = Raphael(overlayDiv,208,270);
var bgr = canvas.rect(10,10, canvas.width-10, canvas.height-10).attr({fill: "0xFF0000", stroke: "none", opacity:"0.2"});

bgr.mousedown( function(e) { alert ("down"); }); //doesn't work
bgr.click( function(e) { alert ("click"); }); // works
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="container" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;"><img class="corePic nonselectable" style="position:relative; top: 0; left: 0;" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Tesla3.jpg/220px-Tesla3.jpg" alt="2_3"><div class="holder nonselectable" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;" onselectstart="return false;"></div></div>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should accept the answer, I think it is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JMu7Z/8/)** I provided based on you example.

```
//bgr.click(function(){this.attr({stroke:'orange',"stroke-width":5,opacity:0.5});
bgr.mousedown(function() 
{
    this.attr({stroke:'red',"stroke-width":5,opacity:0.5}); 
});
bgr.mouseup(function() 
{
    this.attr({stroke:'blue',"stroke-width":5,opacity:0.5}); 
});
//bgr.mousemove(function(){this.attr({stroke:'green',"stroke-width":5,opacity:0.5});
```

Take note that there are some listeners that cannot be used simultaneously.

For example:

- `click` and `mousedown` events should not be used together on the same object. Why? Because the `mosedown` event triggers as soon as you push mouse button down; whereas `click` is different. If you look at the DEMO, comment everything and uncomment `click`. **When you press and hold the mouse button nothing happens until you release the button.** That is why when you have both events on the same object, `mousedown` triggers first and takes over the `click`.
- `mouseup` and `mousemove` also act similar to the previous point. `mousemove` triggers right away and takes over 'mouseup' event. That is why you can only see `mousemove` event on the object that has both events implemented.

---

Plus, **`mousemove`** is really annoying. When you have it, it will not even let you `click`, `mousedown`, or `mouseup` events from happening. In all three cases it triggers and stays on the whole time your mouse is over the element.

*Hope this helped a little.*